# OS X NSStatusItem How to set the accessibility title for VoiceOver

Tags: macos, accessibility, voiceover, nsstatusitem

There is no direct API (as far as I can see) but some applications seem to have it.

Although Apple's own icons (e.g. fast user switching, keyboard layout switching) do not have it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since OS X 10.10, `NSStatusItem` has `button` property, which is a regular `NSView`-based control that conforms to `NSAccessibility` protocol and which allows to change `accessibilityTitle` property directly.

On earlier versions of OS X, you can implement a custom button that looks and behaves exactly like vanilla `NSStatusItem` and assign it to the item via `-[NSStatusItem setView:]` method, then use `-[NSView accessibilitySetOverrideValue:... forAttribute:NSAccessibilityTitleAttribute]` on your custom control to provide a voiceover title.

Comment: Hm are you sure about this? It still says "Menu, 10 items", whatever I seem to try (doing thins on the NSMenu, doing it to the button property, ...)

Comment: I haven't tried it, but this is the only mechanism that controls it. What if you don't set the item's menu, but display it manually in action handler, using `popUpStatusItemMenu:`?

Comment: I still can't get it to work (I'm modifying Qt's qcocoasystemtrayicon.mm) for the non-10.10 solution but I guess you are right with your statements as I've seen the accessibilityTitle in several solutions on github. https://github.com/halo/Brick/blob/44ea46e2f1ff62263e76fc414c1f59f109fcfd0f/Brick/Classes/BrickController.m#L175 https://github.com/gfiumara/stillhere/blob/fa6df178f4ff4e03ecc852959bf795bb6a975ff2/Still%20Here/AppDelegate.m#L96

Comment: Tooltip is read before this title. Is there any way to set order.